# Deploying yii2 advanced application on existing aws e2 instance using Vagrant

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, yii2-advanced-app

I am struggling hard to deploy my Yii2 application on AWS e2 instance using Vagrant. I have Server IP, User name, Access key ID, Secret access key, Console login link and pem file. Is this possible to deploy my yii2 application on aws using above information with Vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with:

```
require 'vagrant-aws'
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
    config.vm.box = 'dummy'
    config.vm.provider 'aws' do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
    aws.secret_access_key = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
    aws.keypair_name = 'ssh-keypair-name'
    aws.instance_type = "t2.micro”
    aws.region = 'us-east-1'
    aws.ami = 'ami-20be7540'
    aws.security_groups = ['default']
    override.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
    override.ssh.private_key_path = '~/.ssh/ssh-keypair-file'
  end
end
```

Check the following pages for more info:

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/using-vagrant-to-deploy-aws-ec2-instances/

and

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws

For "aws.region", find your region. For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: Thanks for replying Reza, I have already tried this but i think this would require aws.region and aws.ami which i don't currently have. I have also tried random aws.region but still won't connect.

Comment: While you are using the AWS services, you always use one of the regions, so find your region.
For more info: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: As i told you before i have tried all these regions, but i think the aws.ami issue will still remain. The app was deployed with capistrano using same credentials, but Vagrant needs aws.ami to deploy the application. Isn't it?

Comment: Based on their documents:  ami - The AMI id to boot, such as "ami-12345678", you can find your AMI id by CLI or EC2 console in AWS.